# Is this a proper usecase for eval() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I've gone through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

I am curious if there is a better way to pass this name of the currently clicked panel name to the `handlePanelClick()`. The line `let currentPanel = eval(`this.${name}Panel`);` is what I am concerned about.

I need to have `name` be evaluated and then set as part of the currentPanel. If I remove the `eval()` to just `'this.${name}Panel'`, then `currentPanel` is not a DOM Element.

Is this a proper use case for using eval()?

```
        export default class Profiles extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.ul, this.hunterPanel, this.fieldPanel, ...
         // other declarations...
        this.handlePanelClick = this.handlePanelClick.bind(this);

       }

      handlePanelClick(event, name) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const currentScrollPosition = this.ul.scrollLeft;

            let currentPanel = eval(`this.${name}Panel`); //  <-- is this good practice or is there a better way? Removing eval() means `this` is a string and not a reference to the DOM Element that was clicked.
        // move the unordered list to the left into the viewport
            TweenMax.to(this.ul, 0.75, { scrollTo: { x: currentPanel.getBoundingClientRect().left + currentScrollPosition } });    
          }

      render() {
        return (
            <section className="video-slider">
            <ul ref={ul => this.ul = ul}>
              <li ref={ hunterPanel => this.hunterPanel = hunterPanel }>
                /* html elements */
              </li>
              <li ref={ fieldPanel => this.fieldPanel = fieldPanel }>
                /* html elements */
              </li>
             </ul>
    <ul>
          <li><a onClick={() => this.handlePanelClick(event, "hunter")}><span>Hunter</span></a></li>
          <li><a onClick={() => this.handlePanelClick(event, "field")}><span>Field</span></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Don't you just need `this[name + "Panel"]`? Also the `event` should be able to tell you what was clicked via `event.target` not sure if you can use that. And `this.handlePanelClick(event, "hunter")}` instead of passing the *name*, why not just pass the panel? `this.handlePanelClick(event, hunterPanel)}`. In short, it seems like a very bad use of `eval`.

Comment: I believe it is correct because I am passing data to eval() instead of code.

Comment: But there is no need for that. Sure, it's safe, since it's not executing any untrusted code but it's still not needed. At the very least, code refactoring would be hampered.

Comment: @vlaz - I'll give your suggestions a try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vlaz - your suggestion worked. I knew eval() had a bad smell.

Comment: with dynamic `a` links you wont be able to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) `[]` to dynamically target a property in an object with a string:

```
this[`${name}Panel`]
```

By the way, `eval` is evil. Try not to use it, beside the security risk the browsers are dumping some optimizations when using `eval` .

Comment: OP claims `this` is a string in that function, so another way to do the same is `this.handlePanelClick(event, "hunter")` to be replaced with `this.handlePanelClick(event, hunterPanel) `, so `handleClick` will just have a reference to the concrete panel needed.

Comment: Eval isn't evil, it's just cases like this one were you shouldn't use it. There are usecases where eval makes sense

Comment: @LucaKiebel if the OP is doing SSR then code injection could be very dangerous. if your running on client only, then you probably get a performance hit. Let's say that if you are not sure if you should use `eval` or not then you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @vlaz where does it says `this` is a string? anyway if the OP needs the element you can grab it via `event.target`?

Comment: @Sagivb.g - I am doing SSR. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

Refactors based off of Sagiv b.g accepted answer, and vlaz suggesions:

refactored more React-ish:

```
<li><a onClick={() => this.handlePanelClick(event, this.hunterPanel)}><span>Hunter</span></a></li>
          <li><a onClick={() => this.handlePanelClick(event, this.fieldPanel)}><span>Field</span></a></li>

handlePanelClick(event, name) {
event.preventDefault();
const currentScrollPosition = this.ul.scrollLeft;

let currentPanel =  name; // don't do this --> eval(`this.${name}Panel`);
// rest of code
}
```

refactored more vanilla javascript-ish:

```
<li><a onClick={() => this.handlePanelClick(event, 'hunter')}><span>Hunter</span></a></li>
          <li><a onClick={() => this.handlePanelClick(event, 'field')}><span>Field</span></a></li>

handlePanelClick(event, name) {
event.preventDefault();
const currentScrollPosition = this.ul.scrollLeft;

let currentPanel =  this[`{name}Panel`]; // don't do this --> eval(`this.${name}Panel`);
// rest of code
}
```